# Unloading data from a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap `3.3.2`. How could I remove the data from `modal`? I want the modal to appear as fresh as it was loaded the first time.

For example a modal like :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mypass" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="mypass">Characteristics</h4>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class='form-inline'>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='playernumber_pass'>Player number</label>
                                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='playernumber_pass' name='playernumber_pass'/>
                            </div>
                            <label class='checbox-inline'>
                                <input type='checkbox' id='completed' name='completed'>Completed
                            </label>                            
                    </form>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when loaded again has the field filled with the previous data. How could I make sure, that the fields and other items inside the modal are loaded fresh?

Here is the fiddle that showing the same data is loaded again, when modal reloads : [**fiddle**](http://www.bootply.com/n3yboZ8eVu)

I tried the following, but it didn't work :

```
$('#pass').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $('#pass').removeData();
})
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to reset the values of any inputs when the modal closes.

Comment: @TroyThompson Is there a better way?

Comment: @TroyThompson There is also an image, that needs to be reset for the changes made.

Answer (score 4):

You could cache `.html()` of the modal and restore it on a [`X.bs.modal` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
var modalFreshContents = $('#pass').html();

// content of the modal will be restored when the modal is fully hidden
$('#pass').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).html(modalFreshContents);
});
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/GLXyNmT5En)

Comment: @SuhailGupta , it's actually one of the easiest ways

Comment: Yes! Does it make a difference if I bind the event on `hide.bs.modal` instead of `hidden.bs.modal`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta  go http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events you can understand difference

Comment: Yes, the changes inside modal would be noticeable to the user if you're using show/hide animations. The difference is that `hide.bs.modal` event is fired immediately when `hide` method has been called (it won't wait for a hide animation, therefore user will notice that the modal is being restored). `hidden.bs.modal` event is fired **after** the modal is fully hidden to the user (will wait until the hide animation is complete).

Comment: @ArturFilipiak I noticed loss in functionality when I empty the modal using this method. I am unable to drag images. Also, when I click the button to submit data, it does nothing.

Comment: @SuhailGupta , there's what you might want to do : https://jsfiddle.net/Lv145325/ (difficult to give a proper answer not seeing the actual code). Basically you have to reinitialize any plugin since the content of the modal has been restored to it's first state. You could handle all the plugins initializations within a method and reapply that method on `hidden.bs.modal`

Comment: can we discuss here at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73470/migrated-from-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-29180155-unloading-data-from-a-m

Answer (score 1):

you can use model on show event. This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.  [check model events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
  $('#pass').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      $('form.form-inline')[0].reset();
  });
```